# Angular <progress> (change) not firing

Tags: angular, progress-bar, onchange

I'm trying to use the HTML5 `<progress></progress>` tag in an Angular application.  I'd like to emit when the progress tag's `value` has reached `100`.  I assumed that I should use a `(change)` event binding like this:

```
<progress max="100" 
          [value]="item.progress" 
          (change)="progressChanged($event)"></progress>
```

I even tried it with a 2-way binding to see if that changed anything.  But I just can't seem to get this `progressChanged` method called.  I assume it's not being called because of what I have in the body of said method:

```js
progressChanged(event) {
  console.log(event);
}
```

How do I bind to events attached to the `<progress></progress>` tag?

Comment: AFAIK unfortunately the HTML5 progress element does not emit a changed event because it is no form input element. You'll probably have to call your progressChanged method whenever you change the value of item.progress instead or make use of an Observable or sth

Comment: you can subscribe to an Observable which emits percentage of completion value at a regular interval and set the value of `item.progress` there